# Azure Node stuck in "Waiting for start task" state after Reboot

Tags: azure, powershell

I'm using Azure Data Factory to run a Powershell script in my project but my script needs to Install-Modules with Admin privileges. I've created the Batch account, Pool, container and ADF Pipeline needed for this case. Followed all the steps mentioned here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1316193/azure-data-factory-running-powershell-script-as-ad?orderby=helpful&comment=answer-1275819#newest-answer-comment

Ran it a few times in ADF and it's successful but in Container it's sending an error log in stderr.txt that the install module needs to run with admin privileges.

I have 3 modules that are needed for my script to run and instead of placing this inside the script itself I've added it in the Pool inside the Start Task.

[image]

I've noticed in the Pool and Node I've created before when I'm not running the pipeline in ADF that their state is in **IDLE**. After making these changes in Start Task I've **rebooted the node** then now it's stuck in **"Waiting for Start Task" state**.

[image]

I've tried running my Pipeline in ADF and it's also stuck in 'In Progress' status.

Do I need to delete the node in this case? Or is it ok not to reboot the node after making these changes in start task?

I thought it's still rebooting but after a day the state is still like this.

Comment: Try running PS script by right click PS shortcut and select run as Admin.  I think the code is exiting so service is not running.  Check with Task Manager to see if service is running.

Comment: You mean in my local machine? but i've ran this using batch pool. Checked it but no services related to powershell that's running.

Comment: Where is you SQL Server?  Is it on your local machine or on a remote machine.  Most likely the connection string has issues to the SQL Server.  Best way of debugging an SQL Server issue is to use SQL Server Management Studio to connect to server.  The SSMS login window will give server\instance name an if you are using Windows Credential or SQL Credentials.  The log files are in the SSMS explorer under Management and will show when you run PS is the credentials passed or failed.  You PS script is download libraries to connect to SQL Server but not actually installing the SQL Server.

Comment: It's on a remote machine. I'm not sure if that's the case because I ran my script in my local machine and it works. No issues in the credentials it's just that I need to RUN it AS ADMIN. I've tried also Install-Module -Name ImportExcel then rebooted the Node and right now it's in Start Task Failed state. Not sure the next step. Is there a way in the Batch or Node to check any logs of the errors? I tried checking the startup folder in Node with stderr and stdout.txt but it's empty.

Comment: Best way of debugging is to use SQL Server Management Studio.  The login window contains the Server\Instance and should also show Windows Credentials.  You run on local machine and verify you can connect to the remote database using the same credentials that is in your connection string.  Integrated Security = true is the same as Windows Credentials.  Any login errors will show in the log files in SSMS.   First step is determine if the login works by viewing the log files.